# Вызвать функцию имея декоратор -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, декоратор

В ряде модулей питон функции вызываются непонятным мне способом, полагаю с помощью декоратора. (Список таких модулей, которые я знаю: `Django`, `Flask`, `Aiogram`, `Pyrogram`, `discord.py`)
Код будет показан на примере Flask

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'heya'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Flask самостоятельно вызывает фунцию `index` имея лишь декоратор.
Как сделать нечто подобное?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот я вам взяв за основу типовой декоратор за 10 минут набросал аналог:

```
class WebServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.doit = {}

    def route(self, path):

        def decorator(function):
            self.doit[path] = function
        return decorator

    def run(self):
        print('Server is running')
        for i,key in enumerate(self.doit):
            print(i, key)
            self.doit[key]()

app = WebServer()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print('Go go go!')

@app.route('/img')
def images():
    print('Images!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Вывод:

```
Server is running
0 /
Go go go!
1 /img
Images!
```

**Update**: Чуть усложнил код, можно прописывать много `route`, они копятся в словарь, который можно потом перебрать.